# If $0<f'\left(x\right)<f\left(x\right)$ and $f\left(0\right)=e$, then $f\left(2e\right)<e^{8}$

Tags: real-analysis

> Let f be continuously differentiable on $[0,+\infty)$. For any $x>0$
>   $0<f'\left(x\right)<f\left(x\right)$. Also, $f\left(0\right)=e$. Show
>   that  $f\left(2e\right)<e^{8}$.

Please, help me to solve this.

Given positive derivative, $f\left(2e\right)>f\left(0\right)=e$. That's all I've come up with.

Comment: Can you show that $e^{-x}f(x)$ is a decreasing function from the conditions provided?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $h(x) = f(x) \cdot \exp(-1-x)$. We have $$h'(x)=\exp(-1-x) \cdot (f'(x)-f(x)) < 0$$, hence

$$1 = h(0) > h(2e) = \frac{f(2e)}{e^{1+2e}}.$$

So we have the even stronger $f(2e) < e^{1+2e}$ with $1+2e \approx 6.43...$

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Let $$F(x)=e^{-x}f(x)\Longrightarrow F'(x)=e^{-x}[f'(x)-f(x)]<0$$
so
$$F(x)<F(0)=e\Longrightarrow f(x)<e^{x+1}$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $0<f'<f$ by assumption, we have $$\frac{d}{dx}\log f=\frac{f'}{f}<1$$
which implies that 
$\log f(x)-\log f(0)=\log f(x)-1\leq x$ since $f(0)=e$, or equivalently
$$\tag{1}f(x)\leq e^{x+1}.$$
It follows from $(1)$ that 
$$f(2e)-f(0)=\int_0^{2e}f'(x)dx<\int_0^{2e}f(x)dx\leq \int_0^{2e}e^{x+1}dx=e^{2e+1}-e.$$
This implies 
$$f(2e)<e^{2e+1}-e+f(0)=e^{2e+1}<e^8.$$

Comment: Shouldn't you use the value of $f(0)$ in the solution of the differential equation (equation $(1)$), and not *after*? so that $\frac{f(x)}{f(0)} \leq e^x$. As stated, the inequality $(1)$ is wrong: if the function is the constant equal to, say, $2$, the differential equation holds but $(1)$ is not true for all $x$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I edited the answer.